# QRGROUP could has a multiple fields in the property expression in quickreports delphi

Tags: delphi, quickreports

In quick report in Delphi how can I use a multiple data fields in qrgroup expression property?

For example I have a table like this one:

```
student  departement   entry year
---------------------------------
1        math          2016
2        math          2017
3        physique      2017
4        math          2016
5        physique      2018
```

I want to regroup my report using departement and entry year.

How can I use it in qrgroup expression property?

Thanks guys

Comment: I would say use a + between the fields in the TQRGroup.Expression, but your fieldnames have spaces, so that may not work as you expect. Are you sure those are actual fieldnames and not just column headings?

Comment: You can use 2 QrGroups instead, one for each field you need grouping